# Model Category presentation of Pointed and Connected $\infty$-categories

Tags: higher-category-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories

Let $(\infty,1)Cat^{*/}_{con}$ denote the $(\infty,1)$-category of pointed and connected $(\infty,1)$-categories (that is, $(\infty,1)$-categories with a distinguished object such that there exists a zigzag of arrows between every two objects). Is there a model category presentation of this? As I recall, the model structure on reduced simplicial sets models the $(\infty,1)$-category of pointed and connected $\infty$-groupoids, which is slightly similar to my situation. Perhaps there is a related notion?

Comment: Model categories model (∞,1)-categories.  How exactly is a model category supposed to model noninvertible 2-morphisms?

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part. We should restrict to the $(\infty,1)$-category of pointed and connected $(\infty,1)$-categories - I'll edit the question.

Comment: How is a pointed connected (∞,1)-category defined in the first place?  Can it have more than one object?  The definitions I know of (see the nLab) say that a pointed category is simply a category with a zero object and a connected category is a category where any pair of objects can be connected by a zigzag of morphisms.  Is this correct?

Comment: @user84563 Note that a pointed space is not pointed when consider as an $(\infty,1)$-category (yeah, the terminology conflict is annoying but we're stuck with it). However in your notation you seem to suggest that by pointed category you mean a category with a distinguished object and not a category with a (non necessarily specified) zero object). Can you clarify the terminology?

Comment: I've clarified in the question. Is the clarification sufficient?

Comment: Such an ∞-category does not have pullbacks (e.g., {0}→{0→1}←{1} doesn't have a pullback), so clearly a presentation by a model category is impossible.